# Remove multiple rows containing particular objects

Tags: r, grepl

Here's a sample of the dataset I'm working on:

```
> head(dataraw)
   ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z     Event Proportion
1:         19         21         28 Vigilance          1
2:         20         14         24 Vigilance          1
3:         34         35         49 End                1
4:         18          5         19 Unknown            1
5:         23         27         35 Vigilance          1
6:         33         20         39 Vigilance          1
```

I would like to transform my data in a way that all rows that contain `End` and `Unknown` in the column `Event` will be deleted. I've been able to do this successfully with one object at the time using this command:

```
datanet1<-dataraw[!grepl("End", dataraw$Event),]
datanet<-datanet1[!grepl("Unknown", datanet1$Event),]
```

However, I would like to do this in one step, but I'm getting errors if using:

```
datanet<-datanet1[!grepl(("Unknown","End"), datanet1$Event),]
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Use the `|` (OR)  `dataraw[!grepl("End|Unknown", Event)]`. Assuming that you want the match the partial strings and it is a data.table

Comment: `df[!df$Event %in% c('End', 'Unknown')]`